# Why is .append() slower than setting the value in a pre-allocated array?

Tags: python, list, time

I'm trying to speed up part of my code that involves looping through and setting the values in a large 2D array. One of the suggestions was that I try pre-allocating the array rather than using .append() but it was pointed out that in Python .append() is an amortized O(1) operation.

However when I tested it using the following code:

```
import time

x = list()
z = list()
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    z.append([])
    for j in range(10000):
        z[i].append(0)

t1 = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    x.append([])
    for j in range(10000):
        x[i].append(1)
print(time.time()-t1)

t1 = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    for j in range(10000):
        z[i][j] = 1
print(time.time()-t1)
```

I consitently get the pre-allocated array taking 3-4 seconds less than the array that isn't preallocated (~17s compared to ~21). What is it in this code that is causing the .append() based function to take longer than replacing the value in a pre-allocated array?

Comment: "Amortized O(1)" means it's O(1) when you consider entire lifetime of the object, and not just any append itself, which is what you're doing right here. And as with any pointless benchmark, it doesn't matter unless you profile entire program and *prove* it matters.

Comment: I don't know much about Python specifically, but with most programming languages, appending to an array (which must be contiguous in memory) usually means having to make space to expand the array, which takes extra time every time you append.

Comment: @NicFoster: The capacity of dynamic arrays is rarely extended by 1. It's more likely to be half of the current capacity or twice that or something like that (that's where amortized thingy comes from).

Comment: You can also use the `dis` module to break down the steps involved in a function.

Comment: You shouldn't use the time module for these sort of benchmarks, typically... I think this is what timeit was written for.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Yes, I know. :) That's generally how it works with most languages. I guess my original comment was incorrect, it doesn't have to make space every time you append, just anytime you append and it has run out of space. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Further- big O notation is about the asymptotic behavior of a function. It's useful for comparing algorithms, not differences in constants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
from dis import dis

def f1():
 x = []
 for i in range(10000):
  x.append([])
  for j in range(10000):
   x[i].append(0)
 return x

dis(f1)

  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           6 SETUP_LOOP              73 (to 82)
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (10000)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 GET_ITER
        >>   19 FOR_ITER                59 (to 81)
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

  4          25 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             28 LOAD_ATTR                1 (append)
             31 BUILD_LIST               0
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             37 POP_TOP

  5          38 SETUP_LOOP              37 (to 78)
             41 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
             44 LOAD_CONST               1 (10000)
             47 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             50 GET_ITER
        >>   51 FOR_ITER                23 (to 77)
             54 STORE_FAST               2 (j)

  6          57 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             60 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             63 BINARY_SUBSCR
             64 LOAD_ATTR                1 (append)
             67 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             70 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             73 POP_TOP
             74 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           51
        >>   77 POP_BLOCK
        >>   78 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           19
        >>   81 POP_BLOCK

  7     >>   82 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             85 RETURN_VALUE
```

Compared with:

```
def f2():
 x = list()
 for i in range(10000):
  x.append([0]*10000)
 return x

dis(f2)

  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           9 SETUP_LOOP              40 (to 52)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 (10000)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             21 GET_ITER
        >>   22 FOR_ITER                26 (to 51)
             25 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

  4          28 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             31 LOAD_ATTR                2 (append)
             34 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             37 BUILD_LIST               1
             40 LOAD_CONST               1 (10000)
             43 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             44 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             47 POP_TOP
             48 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           22
        >>   51 POP_BLOCK

  5     >>   52 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             55 RETURN_VALUE
```

How you approach things can make a huge difference.

Comment: Thanks, that really shows the difference. Will be using the dis module to look at things a lot more in the future.

Answer (score 2):

.append() can cause python to allocate more memory, which takes time. By using the per-allocated structure, you're saving on the time to do all the individual allocations.